# execl() works on one of my code, but doesn't work on another

Tags: c, execl

I already used `execl()` in code, and it worked well.

But this time, I really have no idea why it doesn't work.

So here's the code that do not work

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int i = 896;

     printf("please\n");
     execl("home/ubuntu/server/LC/admin/admin", (char*)i, NULL);
     printf("i have no idea why\n");

     return 0;
}
```

And here's the admin.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int mid = argv[0];

     printf("hi from child\n");
     printf("%d\n", mid);
     return 0;
}
```

Of course I compiled admin.c to admin, and the path isn't wrong.

```
>ls
admin admin.c why why.c
>pwd
/home/ubuntu/server/LC/admin
>./admin
hi from child
-1180858374
>./why
please
i have no ida why
```

Anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Does same path exist on another machine?

Comment: @AmneshGoel Nope. But i'm using AWS cloud computing service. will that be matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My C is a bit rusty but your code made many rookie mistakes.

1. `execl` will replace the current process if it succeeds. So the last line ("i have no idea why") won't print if the child can launch successfully. Which means...
2. `execl` failed and you didn't check for it! Hint: check the typecast to `char *`.
3. You cast an `int` to a `char *` in the `execl` call, then again when you launch the child (`admin`). This is a big no-no in C. It freely allows you to misinterpret types. The only warning is most often a crash. GGC will warn you about it. I don't know about the compiler on AWS.
4. Check your array's bound! You don't know how many parameters `admin` was launched with. `argv[0]` always exist because it contains a representation of the program name. `argv[1]` may not be defined. Accessing array out-of-bound is an undefined behavior and highly dangerous.

The standard way to start another process in C is to `fork` the parent, then call one of the functions in the `exec` family to start the other process.

Consider this instead (I took the liberty to emit different messages to make them clearer).

**parent.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 896;
    char str[15];
    int pid;

    printf("Hello from parent\n");
    sprintf(str, "%d", i); // convert the number into string

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        printf("Fork failed\n");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Continue from parent\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // start the child process
        execl("home/ubuntu/server/LC/admin/admin", str, NULL);

        // check if it started properly
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            printf("Error launching child process: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Goodbye from parent\n");    
    return 0;
}
```

**admin.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * mid;

    // argc is always 1 or more
    if (argc >= 2)
        mid = argv[1];
    else
        mid = "<nothing>";

    printf("hello from child\n");
    printf("argc = %d, argv[1] = %s\n", argc, mid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! apparently, casting was the problem. i thought that argument has type 'char*' and argv[] is something like 'arv[] = {(char*),(char*)....}' so i just cast 'int' to 'char*'......  anyway, thanks again. should be more careful about data types next time.